# Bootstrap Grid Row does not align center if hidden then shown with JS

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5, bootstrap-grid

Apologies in advance for the wonky indentation.

I have a simple Bootstrap Grid setup like so

```
<div class="row justify-content-center" align="center" id="details">
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h4><?php echo getDAtimeWorked($envelope); ?></h4>
                 <h5 id=""><?php echo getDArecords($envelope); ?></h5>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <h4><?php echo getTNtimeWorked($envelope); ?></h4>
                    <h5 id=""><?php echo getTNrecords($envelope); ?></h5>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <h4><?php echo getMHtimeWorked($envelope); ?></h4>
                    <h5 id=""><?php echo getMHrecords($envelope); ?></h5>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <h4><?php echo getLTtimeWorked($envelope); ?></h4>
                    <h5 id=""><?php echo getLTrecords($envelope); ?></h5>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-body">
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

function showDetails() {
  var x = document.getElementById("details");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

When I click on that cell to toggle show/hide, the hidden and then shown content is no longer aligned center.  How can I get it to?

My end goal for transparency is to hide that content on page load and reveal it onclick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your js, you're switching it to block, `x.style.display = "block"` , so the class `justify-content-center` stops working because it's not a flex anymore.

Try `x.style.display = "flex"` instead.

Comment: Magic!  Thank you!!
Will mark as the working answer in a few minutes when the cooldown expires.